# How to correctly manage positions of objects for application compatible with iPhone, iPad iPod different resolutions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing game and I have general question about managing all positions of hundreds of objects.Previously it was a lot easier because there was only one point which was universal for iPhone 3, iPhone 4 iPod touche etc. Now there are different aspect ratios and different resolutions. 
I want my game to be compatible with all major devices which are:

iPhone5, iPhone5s, iPhone5c 1136 x 640  ~16:9

iPod 5Gen                   1136 x 640  ~16:9

iPhone4, iPhone4s           960 × 640   3:2

iPod 4Gen                   960 × 640   3:2

iPad 3Gen, iPad 4Gen, iPad Air  2048 × 1536 4:3

iPad Mini Second Gen            2048 × 1536 4:3

iPad2                           1024 × 768  4:3

iPad Mini First Gen         1024 × 768  4:3

First of all I want to correctly identify these Devices. Currently I'm doing this 
`if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` to differentiate ipad and

```
if ((screenHeight==568) && (uiscale==2.0f)) {
           // it is iphone5
        }
```

to find iphone5. With same approach I'm going to identify different iPads. 
 is it correct way? 
 Now about coordinates currently I have positions calculation block in init of each scene. I'm trying to have relative coordinates to screen size, for example `posY=winSize.height*0.5f;` not to hard code each coordinate. I want to have some shared instance where will be defined once what kind of device is running application, what is screen size etc. and all such calculations will took place for example `mainMenuPlayButtonX=winSize.height*0.5f; or gameScenePauseButtonX=winSize.height*0.5f;` and etc. 
 will it be correct? Please share what to do.

Comment: Are these general objects in the same (non-moving) position...such as controls, or are they actual game elements?

Comment: These are non-moving objects, game and menu like towers, guns, and also buttons, status bar, joystick etc.

Comment: If they aren't moving, then the suggestion I made below about fixed percentages for a nominal geometry with alternative positioning for "geometries that are too different" may be the best option.  Check out  answer I gave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two major problems with different screen geometries.

1. Art sized for a particular geometry will usually not work out properly when you try to use it in different one (e.g. landscape for portrait, 4:3 vs. 16:9, etc.).
2. The positions of items on the screens move around and may not always look good.

Let's do the first one first ([this is from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426542/trying-to-figure-out-how-to-match-aspect-ratio-on-mac-to-android/20426879#20426879)):

***Artwork Sizing***

I have made several Apps for iOS and have "the aspect ratio problem" problem with graphics for buttons and backgrounds when going between iPhone and iPad, which have different aspect ratios. Throw orientation into the mix as well.

I use Gimp, Inkscape, Spine, Cocos2d-x, and lots of other tools for reference.

As far as I know, the general options for "different screen geometry" issues are (if there are others, let me know):

1. Different graphics for each geometry.
2. Scaling the graphics proportionally for the geometry.
3. Same graphics for all, scale proportionally based on one dimension
       and then place graphics on screen using percentages for fixed stuff.

***Option 1*** means extra work...not acceptable for a hobbyist or indie (like me) developer.

***Option 2*** usually looks like junk. Frustration and sadness usually ensue.

***Option 3*** is the option I use most often. I find that occasionally I have to add small changes (read: hacks) based on the device or geometry. In the case of iOS, it is not too bad, because there are only two geometries to deal with. In the case of Android, where there are lots of different tablet geometries, you could cut it down by working with ranges of geometries and picking a fixed orientation for your application.

At the end of the day, proportional scaling by a single dimension (height or width) has gotten me the most bang for the buck.

I usually make the graphics a little "bigger" than I will need so I only have to scale down. This consumes a bit more memory, but I re-use a lot, use sprite sheets, etc. There is a definite tradeoff with managing every bit of memory (which you have to do in a large AAA rated game) and what you can get away with in a small independent application. I am not encouraging sloppiness or memory mismanagement; I'm encouraging balancing the resources against the developmental needs of simplicity...making the same graphics for different situations burns a lot of daylight.

***UI Element Positions***
This is specifically for items like menu buttons, fire buttons, joysticks, etc.  In general, I create a table which contains the scale and position in percentage of screen size for the nominal screen proportion.  When each element is created, it looks up its nominal information in the table and uses it.

Then I create a few copies of this for other major geometries and change the pointer to the table at runtime.  So I may have a 4:3 "portrait" table, a 19:16 "landscape" table, etc. During development I tweak the "other tables" as needed. I usually only need to create a few of these.

** This is an example of this approach: **

**DeviceGeometry.h**

```
#ifndef __MultiDimension__DeviceGeometry__
#define __MultiDimension__DeviceGeometry__

#include "cocos2d.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

class DeviceGeometry
{
public:
    DeviceGeometry();
    virtual ~DeviceGeometry();

   typedef enum
   {
      SG_1024_768 = 0,
      SG_16_9,
      SG_MAX
   } SCREEN_GEOMETRY_T;


   typedef enum
   {
      SE_JOYSTICK = 0,
      SE_LEFT_FIRE_1,
      SE_LEFT_FIRE_2,
      SE_EXIT,
      SE_MAX
   } SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T;

   typedef struct
   {
      // You can include any other pieces of information
      // here as well to fine tune the placement or
      // use of the element.
      SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T element;
      CCPoint position;
      float scale;
   } SCREEN_ELEMENT_DATA_T;


   // Call this when you need to change to a different
   // geometry.
   void Init(SCREEN_GEOMETRY_T geometry);
   CCPoint GetPosition(SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T element);
   float GetScale(SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T element);

protected:
private:
   SCREEN_ELEMENT_DATA_T* _elements;
};

#endif /* defined(__MultiDimension__DeviceGeometry__) */
```

**DeviceGeometry.cpp**

```
#include "DeviceGeometry.h"

DeviceGeometry::SCREEN_ELEMENT_DATA_T _elements_1024_768[DeviceGeometry::SE_MAX] =
{
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_JOYSTICK,    ccp(0.8f,    0.1f),    1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_LEFT_FIRE_1, ccp(0.2f,    0.075f),  1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_LEFT_FIRE_2, ccp(0.2f,    0.15f),   1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_EXIT,        ccp(0.1f,    0.9f),    1.0f  },
};

DeviceGeometry::SCREEN_ELEMENT_DATA_T _elements_16_9[DeviceGeometry::SE_MAX] =
{
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_JOYSTICK,    ccp(0.9f,    0.1f),    1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_LEFT_FIRE_1, ccp(0.15f,   0.075f),  1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_LEFT_FIRE_2, ccp(0.15f,   0.15f),   1.0f  },
   { DeviceGeometry::SE_EXIT,        ccp(0.125f,  0.925f),  1.0f  },
};

DeviceGeometry::DeviceGeometry()
{
    _elements = _elements_1024_768;
}

DeviceGeometry::~DeviceGeometry()
{

}

void DeviceGeometry::Init(SCREEN_GEOMETRY_T geometry)
{
   switch(geometry)
   {
      case SG_1024_768:
         _elements = _elements_1024_768;
         break;
      case SG_16_9:
         _elements = _elements_16_9;
         break;
      default:
         assert(false);
         break;
   }
}

CCPoint DeviceGeometry::GetPosition(SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T element)
{
   // Sanity checks.
   assert(element < SE_MAX);
   assert(_elements[element].element == element);

   if(_elements[element].element == element)
   {
      CCPoint& pt = _elements[element].position;
      CCSize scrSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
      return ccp(pt.x * scrSize.width, pt.y * scrSize.height);
   }
   return ccp(0,0);
}


float DeviceGeometry::GetScale(SCREEN_ELEMENTS_T element)
{
   // Sanity checks.
   assert(element < SE_MAX);
   assert(_elements[element].element == element);

   if(_elements[element].element == element)
   {
      return _elements[element].scale;
   }
   return 1.0;
}
```

***Game Element Positions***
This is for the position of all the major game elements themselves...spaceships, meteors, asteroids, etc.  For this, I use a Viewport approach.  This is a bit more complicated.  [See this post for details](http://nonlinearideas.com/viewports/).

Was this helpful?

Comment: I'm using also 3rd option, i.e have one artwork for each aspect ratio (one which is bigger resoultion) and scale down via texturepacker script during build. Table you mean DataBase table?

Comment: No database unless you like to hurt yourself...at least not for this kind of stuff.  Static table of structures in .cpp file.  I'm a bit old school but it works.  You can build the table any way you like;  in this case, it may be better to say "tabulated data".

Comment: Also, just to keep things simple, I don't really support HD options.  It requires 2x the graphics and the artwork doesn't really look that much better.  Your mileage and need may vary here...

Comment: Please can you post example how this cpp file works? there is only static table or also calculations like "posY=winSize.height*0.5f;" That's exactly idea I asked about, to have these calculations and statically assigned coordinates somewhere in shared instance and use it in every scene.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have all information to plan future steps now

Comment: @Grixol Glad I could help.  Fee free to accept as answer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Retina and non-Retina devices use the same coordinate system (points, not pixels)? So you truly only have 3 different screen sizes to support: iPhone, iPhone widescreen and iPad.

Furthermore you can design the iPhone version as if it were running on iPhone widescreen, just make sure you don't display crucial information or user interface elements at the borders where they might be cut off. Alternatively you can decide for individual elements to position them relative to the current device's screen border, which would move them further apart on widescreen but will keep them at the border on regular iPhone screens.

Comment: Yes I have only 3 aspect ratio to support, but because they are different simple scale down may not work. Unfortunately I have to place objects at borders, for example status bar of game must be placed at top border on the screen. So I might need place to have such calculations and don't know were to place, in init of each method or consolidate in some shared instance and use everywhere

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. You want a node to always be aligned to the top? Then set its position.y to director.viewSize.height minus some offset (ie sprite.contentSize.height / 2). You want a node always at the right side of the screen in landscape? Set its position.x to director.viewSize.width minus some offset. That is all.

Comment: Yes you are right, I also do this way, it is not good example. But what about object somewhere in the middle? which is OK in the middle in iPhone 4 but it looks better a little bit up in iPhone 5 because there is more space available. I have to write somewhere "If device is iphone 5 shift this and this object a little bit up"

Comment: Also there will be such "if" for iPad. So I'm looking better way where to implement these ifs, in init of each scene? maybe better to have it somewhere centralized?

Comment: you could use a design tool like spritebuilder or use percentage of screen size as position. Check this: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/12/scaling-cocos2d-node-positions-display-resolution/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have all information to plan future steps now